# Comparison error

Tags: comparisons

Because of its innovativeness and its effective presentation, Mary's science project received more judges' votes at the exhibit than **did Jim**.

The "did Jim" part was incorrect, and I was kind of confused on how this is a comparison error?

Comment: The use of innovativeness sounds a bit off. It refers to a skill. The word innovation could be used instead because it would refer to the object in question (Mary's science project). Source: Dictionary.com

Comment: Yes, I think there might be general confusion here between the people and their projects.  My guess is that the OP wants to say that Mary, and not her science project, is innovative, and that she presented the project effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the votes received by their science projects.

- did Jim's

would be the correct comparison

Comment: IOW, you do not want to compare *Mary's science project* with Jim. You want to compare it with *Jim's science project*, which you can abbreviate as just *Jim's*.  (This is not so much an English question as a logic question.  But I guess if you have some difficulty with English then it can also be difficult to express the logic.)

Comment: Also, I would revert the phrase back to its standard order: _did Jim's_. Compare "She did more work than I did".